# Sessions & ContentPlaceHolders

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, contentplaceholder

Is it possible to set a Container(ContentPlaceHolder) in the MasterPage, and hide it whenever wished ?

For example, I want to put a 2 textboxes and a button for a user to login, but if the session is still running (i.e. user already logged in) I want the change those 2 textboxes and button to a welcome message (for example: "Welcome, Username").

[image]

MasterPage (Note: Not everything is coded)

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<script runat="server">

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim loginSQL As New SqlCommand
        Dim loginComm As String

        Dim CommonFunctions As New CommonFunctions()
        Dim dec_pass As String = CommonFunctions.EncryptPassword(txtLoginPass.Text.Trim)

        Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=BRIAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master_db;Integrated Security=True")


        loginComm = "SELECT userid FROM users WHERE username=@username and password=@password"

        conn.Open()


        loginSQL = New SqlCommand(loginComm, conn)
        loginSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtLoginUser.Text.ToString)
        loginSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", dec_pass)
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = loginSQL.ExecuteReader()

        If dr.HasRows Then
            Session("userid") = dr("userid")
        ElseIf dr.HasRows = False Then
            lblRegister.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            lblRegister.Text = "Incorrect Username/Password."
        End If

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        If Session("userid") <> "" Then
            txtLoginUser.Visible = False
            txtLoginPass.Visible = False
        Else

            Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=BRIAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master_db;Integrated Security=True")

            Dim useridComm As String = "SELECT name, surname FROM users WHERE userid=@userid"
            Dim sqlUserID As New SqlCommand

            conn.Open()

            Dim userid As String = Session("userid")

            sqlUserID = New SqlCommand(useridComm, conn)
            sqlUserID.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", userid)
            Dim datareader As SqlDataReader = sqlUserID.ExecuteReader()

            lblLoggedIn.Text = "Welcome," + txtLoginUser.Text
        End If
    End Sub

</script>



<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
</head>

<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">

<div id="wrapper">

    <header id="header">
        <strong>Header:</strong> Mobile CMS

        </header>


<section id="login">

    <div id="login-form">



            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">

                <p>

                    <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="U:"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtLoginUser" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0px" Wrap="False"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;
                    <asp:Label ID="lblUsername0" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="P:"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLoginPass" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0px" TextMode="Password" Wrap="False"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;
                    <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Login" />

                </p>

                <p>

                    <asp:Label ID="lblRegister" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#0000CC" Text="Register"></asp:Label>

                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder3" runat="server">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblLoggedIn" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

                </p>


                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>



    </div>

</section>

<div class="navigation-bar">
       <ul class="navigation-menu">

            <li><a href="#" class="home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="mainsettings">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="profile">Profile</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="messages">Messages</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="settings">Profile Settings</a></li>
                </ul>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="uploads">Uploads</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="documents">Media</a>


                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="docs">Documents</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="others">Others</a></li>
                </ul>

            </li>

            <li><a href="#" class="projects">Projects</a>


                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="yprojects">Your Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="otherprojects">Other Projects</a></li>
                </ul>

            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>


    <section id="middle">

        <div id="container">
            <div id="content">
                <div>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
        </div>
        </div>



    </section>

    <footer id="footer">
        <strong>Footer:</strong> adsfdsgfds
    </footer>

</div>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You're going to have to post the html that includes the controls so we can see how the page is structured.

Comment: You can just simple use **Visible="true|false"** based on user is `Authenticated` or not. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Win Yes, I read something about content place holders and you can do that. So the best way would be to make 2 content place holders, where 1 is visible when the other isn't, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you have a `ContentPlaceHolder` inside another `ContentPlaceHolder` and I can't see any reason for this.

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder3" runat="server">
   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
```

To the matter in hand, I would hide the controls contained within the `ContentPlaceHolder` depending on whether the user is logged in or not, rather than hiding the placeholder, however this is up to you. I would also add the `userid` column to your SQL query.

The follwing should get you started, note this is **untested** off the top of my head:

`SELECT userid, username, password FROM users ....`

```
If dr.HasRows Then
  Session("userid") = dr("userid")
ElseIf dr.HasRows = False Then
   lblRegister.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
   lblRegister.Text = "Incorrect Username/Password."
End If
```

Now that you have this, you can check the Session variable on `Page_Load` to see if the user is logged in.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  If Session("userid") <> "" Then
    txtLoginUser.Visible = False
    txtLoginPass.Visible = False
  Else
    'Set your label text here, query the database to get the First and Second name of the user using the `userid`
  End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT**
You need to close your readers after you have finished reading:

`dr.Close()` and `datareader.Close()`

Also this line `lblLoggedIn.Text = "Welcome," + txtLoginUser.Text` needs to be:

```
lblLoggedIn.Text = datareader("name").ToString() & " " &
datareader("surname").ToString()
```

Comment: Hi. I tried to do it by hiding/showing ContentPlaceHolders, and it's giving me this error: `The parameterized query '(@username nvarchar(7),@password nvarchar(4000))SELECT username,' expects the parameter '@password', which was not supplied.` on this line `Dim dr As SqlDataReader = loginSQL.ExecuteReader()`

Comment: Don't you need to encrypt the value provided in the textbox? Rather than decrypt?

Comment: Doing as you said, I get an error: `The parameterized query '(@userid nvarchar(4000))SELECT name, surname FROM users WHERE us' expects the parameter '@userid', which was not supplied.` I updated the question with the new code.

Comment: Yes, at page load. `Dim userid As String = Session("userid")
            
                sqlUserID = New SqlCommand(useridComm, conn)
                sqlUserID.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", userid)
                Dim datareader As SqlDataReader = sqlUserID.ExecuteReader()`

Comment: You have the operator in you page load the wrong way around. Change `<>` to `=`

Comment: Hmm, I did that, however, now the page doesn't load (it keeps searching in the browser). Is there some kind of un-closed loop ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27436/discussion-between-brian-and-jack-pettinger)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you want to use ASP.Net `LoginView` and `LoginStatus` control.

Since you only have one page, just use two `Panels` - show and hide based on user is Authenticated or not.

NOTE: do not use `ContentPlaceHolder` for this case.

**Update:**

Here is the sample code for `LoginView` if you want to try. It is a prefer way of doing it.

```
%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm6.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="WebApplication2010.WebForm6" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
        <AnonymousTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="U:"></asp:Label>
            &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtLoginUser" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0px"
                TextMode="Password" Wrap="False"></asp:TextBox>
            &nbsp;
            <asp:Label ID="lblUsername0" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="P:"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLoginPass" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0px"
                TextMode="Password" Wrap="False"></asp:TextBox>
            &nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" OnClick="Button1_Click"
                Text="Login" />
        </AnonymousTemplate>
        <LoggedInTemplate>
            Welcome!
        </LoggedInTemplate>
    </asp:LoginView>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var txtLoginUser = LoginView1.FindControl("txtLoginUser") as TextBox;
    var txtLoginPass = LoginView1.FindControl("txtLoginPass") as TextBox;

    // Your authentication

    // If validation is successful, create Authentication ticket
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtLoginUser.Text, false);
}
```